# toFixed() replacement function

Tags: javascript, firefox, math

I have noticed that many people are having trouble with the toFixed() method in javascript.

I, myself, had a website that was throwing fits in IE7 and FireFox 4.x.

I finally found the problem was the toFixed() method. It seemed to return a string in some browsers and not in others - it seems to act unpredictably.

Rather than have to do the same parseFloat/integer gymnastics every time I use this method, I decided to just extend the prototype object and create my own method.

With this method you can round to any number of decimal places AND you can specify the type of rounding to use: floor, ceil, or null to use standard rounding (round).

CODE:

```
     // a replacement for the toFixed() function in javascript

    Number.prototype.trimNum = function(places,rounding){

    var places,result,num = parseFloat(this),multiplier = Math.pow( 10,places );

    try {
        result = Math[rounding](num * multiplier) / multiplier;
    } catch(e){
        result = Math.round(num * multiplier) / multiplier; 
    }

    return Number( result );
}
```

USAGE:

`mynumbervar.trimNum(2,'floor')` to round using floor

`mynumbervar.trimNum(2,'ceil')` to round using ceil

`mynumbervar.trimNum(2)` to round using round

Of course the number "2" here would be the number of decimal places to preserve.

I have tested it in IE, Safari, Chrome, and FireFox on the PC and mac and it seems to be working well for me.

I hope this helps someone else avoid the toFixed() headaches I had....

Does anyone know of any problems with this or any suggestions to improve it?

Comment: You should formulate this as proper question and provide your solution as answer.

Comment: Seriosuly? What is the point of that. This forum is to help people not just to get points...

Comment: exoboy, this is not a discussion forum. SO is a Q&A site.

Comment: @exoboy: Yes. Seriously. You might want to read this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I am not offering or opening a DISCUSSION. Since there are so many other people with the same problem I am trying to answer an overall issue - not just a specific question. Sorry if this doesn't fit into your life-box.

Comment: @felix it is also okay to wear a pointy hat, but it is not required. Don't anything better to do? I think you are missing the spirit of this site: to help others, not to beat down the ones that do not do things the way you think they should.

Comment: You can turn it into a question, by ending your post with:  "Does anyone know of any problems with this or any suggestions to improve it?"

Comment: @exoboy I really don't know why you are reacting so harshly, or if you even realize how rude you sound.  The Q-A format is the basis of SO.  It's so that the site functions well, not just for points.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the sugestion. Maybe it will placate those who have a strange need to nit-pic.

Comment: @Renesis I apologize if I sound harsh or defensive, but I am tired of people missing the positive spirit that a post is offered in and jumping all over the author because it does not fit their personal views on what is and is not a good or appropriate post.

Comment: @exoboy: I actually just wanted to help you and prevent your "question" from being closed. This post in its current from fits more on your personal blog, but not here. Simply stating the issue in a question form and providing your code and solution as answer, would have been fine. I did not discourage you to present your own solution (you might have noticed that I did not vote to close nor did I down vote). And that this is a Q&A site is not my personal view but a fact.

Comment: But another thing: Are you sure `toFixed()` behaves differently in browsers? Can you verify that somehow? Which browsers? The [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.7.4.5) clearly says that a string has to be returned. I'm just curious.

Comment: Come on guys!  He made it into a question like you asked.  Please re-open.  This is a legitimate programming thing to ask questions about.

Comment: @jfriend00: In this case it should actually go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Felix, yes I am sure it works erratically in IE7 (standards) and FireFox 4/5

Comment: @exoboy.  If you change your question to: "Are there any downsides to adding a prototype to Number like this and are there any problems with the way this is written or improvements you would suggest?"

Comment: @exoboy: Mhh. I cannot say anything about IE (but the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sstyff0z(v=vs.94).aspx) states that it returns a string). But Firefox 3.6 and Firefox 5 *do* return a string (I don't think that changed in FF4).

Comment: @jfriend thanks for the support, but these guys have sucked the life out of this issues so I really have to get back to my primary job as a web designer and not Don Quixote jousting at their overly-critical windmills. It is people like them that discourage growth and change for a lot of people who are not willing to stand up to them.

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions for the function:

Why declare a local variable "places" when that's a parameter passed in?
You don't really need the try/catch.  You could just default the rounding parameter to "round".

```
// a replacement for the toFixed() function in javascript

Number.prototype.trimNum = function(places, rounding) {
    rounding = rounding || "round";
    var num = parseFloat(this), multiplier = Math.pow(10, places);
    return(Number(Math[rounding](num * multiplier) / multiplier));
}
```

The only syntactical difference with this one is that it will fail if a bad value for rounding is passed in whereas yours would have used "round" in that case.  I think it's probably better to fail if a bad operation is passed in.

Here's a working example with a bunch of test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5KRBK/.

Comment: I declared the places var by accident. Also, I forgot to use the || operator, so nice catch. THIS is what I was hoping for - people taking what I did and improving it so we can all benefit. THX!

Comment: Noooo! It is never good to just fail. I simply want it to fail gracefully so that the people who do not know the difference between ceil and floor are not required to declare the rounding method. So, falling back to "round" is actually critical for me.

Comment: See if you can address the error and repost your code. I will probably end up giving you the credit for an answer.

Comment: You misunderstood.  My version still defaults to round if nothing is passed in (you can try it).  But if someone passed myNum.trimNum(4, "foo"), my version will throw an exception because that's an illegal operation.  Your version would silently switch to "round".  I think it's better to throw an error when the instruction was clearly wrong and you really have no idea what the user expected you to do.  My version will work just like yours if they call myNum.trimNum(4).

Comment: I do undertand what you were saying. And you have a good point, but for my purposes I would like to to silently fail since it will still return a valid result. So, no need to post your revised code. I think this might be better for the majority of people out there and anyone in my situation can easily adapt it.

Comment: Working example here with test cases: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5KRBK/

Comment: My solution/question just got closed by the following pinheads. Thanks for your support anyway! I am frankly getting tired of their BS and this may be my last post. So, thanks for having an open mind. THE PINHEADS: closed as not a real question by kingjiv, Marc B, Vivin Paliath, Renesis, cwolves 4 mins ago

Comment: @exoboy: Don't get too upset (and now you are really being rude). After all, this was not a question. I suggest to start a blog where you can create these kind of posts. This will help others too.

Comment: Your version also has problems with trailing zeroes (it won't include them).  See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5KRBK/.

Comment: I actually don't want anything past the decimal if it is just a zero. I simply add those when needed. For mathematical calculations (which this is for), I need just the number and whatever relevant digits are past the decimal.

Comment: OK, that's yet another way that it's different than toFixed() then.